# Using StartAt from Firebase with Flutter Timestamps

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm saving some posts on Firestore with a timestamp property and then I query this posts ordered by timestamp. I'm trying to create a "loadMore" function then works when the user scrolls to bottom and loads more posts.

I'm saving the posts this way:

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('posts')
  .add(<String, dynamic> {
     'content': 'content,
     'likes': 0,
     'comments': 0,
     'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
   })
```

And trying to query this way:

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('posts')
  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
  .startAfter(
    []..add(posts.last.timestamp)
  )
  ..limit(5)
```

But, it keeps ignoring the "startAfter" and returning me a list starting with the first element of the collection and not with the next ones.

Would love to get help using this type of query :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert the DateTime to Unix date-time

```
'timestamp': DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

Comment: It worked. I would prefer to use DateTime format to a more friendly way to see the data in the database, but, I can live with this for now. To retrieve data I'm using: `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(doc.data['timestamp'], isUtc: true),`

Comment: Firebase and Firestore use unix datetime format (millisecs since epoch), The Firebase client can't know when to convert, so you have to take care yourself. Your code to retrieve looks good.